# How to make crontab run new version of my script

Tags: cron

I have currently running python script on debian system. Now because of some reasons I changed this script and updated cron, but nothing has changed. Also, I tried to save this cron in different file and create new cron - line with job appears, but script doesn't work.

```
CRON[22310] (root) CMD ( /usr/bin/python /home/radmin/test/test.py)
```

from /etc/crontab for new script:

```
*/1 * * * * root /usr/bin/python /home/radmin/test/test.py
```

for old script:

```
*/1 * * * * root python /home/radmin/base.py
```

Script runs correctly without cron.

Tried restarting and reloading cron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in python code. Crontab is okay. I'm using python lib "requests" and there is a method to get post request content - ".text", so this method doesn't want to work in cron (empty error logs while running) (still don't know why). So changing .text to .content solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like cron dosen't recognize the `root` command you add.

try instead opening cron using `sudo crontab -e` and then add your code:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/radmin/test/test.py
```

by opening it up with `sudo` it will add it to the root user cron jobs.